# How to upload a file using XWalkWebView

Tags: javascript, android, html, crosswalk

I got a project that I'm working on and it's mostly done in XWalkWebView, I'm at a point where it's a simple file chooser for a picture upload; but when I click on Choose File (Works inside normal PC browser) nothing happens. This is very frustrating as everything was going smoothly until I got to this point... :(

```
private XWalkView xWalkWebView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.chatroom);

    xWalkWebView=(XWalkView)findViewById(R.id.xwalkWebView);
    xWalkWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
    xWalkWebView.load("http://myURL.com/picture_upload.php", null); }
    public class WebAppInterface {
        @org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
                                  public void callFunction(){

        // Do your Android Stuff here

    }
    }


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (xWalkWebView != null) {
        xWalkWebView.pauseTimers();
        xWalkWebView.onHide();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (xWalkWebView != null) {
        xWalkWebView.resumeTimers();
        xWalkWebView.onShow();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (xWalkWebView != null) {
        xWalkWebView.onDestroy();
    }
}
```